# How do I change the date format? (YII)

Tags: php, date, yii, format

I'm using the YII framework... and I am displaying my date using the following code:

```
<?php echo $classified->created_date ?>
```

Problem is that it shows it like this:
2012-11-04 09:34:03

How can I remove the time and just show the date?

And maybe if possible show it like this:
20 Jan 2012 (with the month shortened)

Comment: what are you using to generate the date time? before you echo it

Comment: also you can set how to MySQL return date format by set `SET @@SESSION.DATETIME_FORMAT = '%d %b %Y';`, see also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Yii's `CFormatter` class:

```
echo Yii::app()->format->date(strtotime($classified->created_date));
```

You can extend CFormatter into your own class, and then format the date however you would like, you would just need to include your new component class in the main config file.

Another option is using Yii's date parser and dateFormatter:

```
echo Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(CDateTimeParser::parse($classified->create_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'medium',null);
```

There are many ways to do this...  You can use standard PHP if you want to.  The only draw back to this is that if you decide to change formats, you may have to change many different views:

```
echo date("m/d/Y",strtotime($classified->create_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime($classified->created_date, 'medium', false);
```

more examples for date format look here :
http://www.yiiplayground.com/index.php?r=InternationalizationModule/datetime/basic

Answer (score 1):

this was my solution for the date problem, the date formater wont work for me

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'fecha_inicio'); ?>
    <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'fecha_inicio'); 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
        'name'=>'Eventos[fecha_inicio]',
        // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
        'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'fold',
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'value' => 'yy-mm-dd',
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'placeholder'=>'Fecha',
        ),
    ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'fecha_inicio'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the php date function. date(format, epoch_timestamp)

See here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Hey, I tried: <?php echo $classified->created_date("D, d M Y", $timestamp) ?> but that didn't work... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: PHPs Date function only accepts integer timestamps to format.

Comment: integer timestamp is simply the number of seconds since epoch (1/1/1970)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You should use this code below:

```
Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("dd MMM yyyy", $classified->create_data)
```

which change formatting default settings form 2012-11-04 09:34:03 on 20 Jan 2012

link to doc/api:

[format](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDateFormatter#format-detail)